# .16 - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'quartzScheduler'

Tags: spring

```
.16:17:41.823 [main] WARN  o.s.w.c.s.XmlWebApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'quartzScheduler' defined in URL [file:/C:/Users/SIVASHANKAR/New%20folder/CIMACS/SmartCBSService/target/classes/config/services.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.quartz.SchedulerException: Registration of jobs and triggers failed: Found interface org.quartz.Trigger, but class was expected 
.16:17:41.823 [main] WARN  o.s.w.c.s.XmlWebApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'quartzScheduler' defined in URL [file:/C:/Users/SIVASHANKAR/New%20folder/CIMACS/SmartCBSService/target/classes/config/services.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.quartz.SchedulerException: Registration of jobs and triggers failed: Found interface org.quartz.Trigger, but class was expected 
.16:17:41.941 [main] ERROR o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'quartzScheduler' defined in URL [file:/C:/Users/SIVASHANKAR/New%20folder/CIMACS/SmartCBSService/target/classes/config/services.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.quartz.SchedulerException: Registration of jobs and triggers failed: Found interface org.quartz.Trigger, but class was expected
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:753) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:838) ~[spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537) ~[spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:549) [jetty-6.1.26.jar:6.1.26]
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:136) [jetty-6.1.26.jar:6.1.26]
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1282) [jetty-6.1.26.jar:6.1.26]
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:518) [jetty-6.1.26.jar:6.1.26]
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:499) [jetty-6.1.26.jar:6.1.26]
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50) [jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:6.1.26]
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130) [jetty-6.1.26.jar:6.1.26]
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224) [jetty-6.1.26.jar:6.1.26]
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50) [jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:6.1.26]
    at runjettyrun.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:97) [bootstrap.jar:na]
Caused by: org.quartz.SchedulerException: Registration of jobs and triggers failed: Found interface org.quartz.Trigger, but class was expected
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean.registerJobsAndTriggers(SchedulerFactoryBean.java:800) ~[spring-support-2.0.6.jar:2.0.6]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(SchedulerFactoryBean.java:601) ~[spring-support-2.0.6.jar:2.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
.16:17:41.941 [main] ERROR o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'quartzScheduler' defined in URL [file:/C:/Users/SIVASHANKAR/New%20folder/CIMACS/SmartCBSService/target/classes/config/services.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.quartz.SchedulerException: Registration of jobs and triggers failed: Found interface org.quartz.Trigger, but class was expected
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:753) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:838) ~[spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537) ~[spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:549) [jetty-6.1.26.jar:6.1.26]
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:136) [jetty-6.1.26.jar:6.1.26]
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1282) [jetty-6.1.26.jar:6.1.26]
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:518) [jetty-6.1.26.jar:6.1.26]
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:499) [jetty-6.1.26.jar:6.1.26]
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50) [jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:6.1.26]
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130) [jetty-6.1.26.jar:6.1.26]
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224) [jetty-6.1.26.jar:6.1.26]
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50) [jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:6.1.26]
    at runjettyrun.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:97) [bootstrap.jar:na]
Caused by: org.quartz.SchedulerException: Registration of jobs and triggers failed: Found interface org.quartz.Trigger, but class was expected
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean.registerJobsAndTriggers(SchedulerFactoryBean.java:800) ~[spring-support-2.0.6.jar:2.0.6]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(SchedulerFactoryBean.java:601) ~[spring-support-2.0.6.jar:2.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Looks like incompatible jar Versions in your Project. BTW: read [ask]

Comment: Find out where the conflict is and use the correct version

Comment: i was unable to share another link because my reputation was below 10

Comment: Do not share it as link. add it to your question using the edit function

Comment: Remove `spring-support` jar... You are mixing spring 2.0.6 and 4.2.3 jars never mix jars of different version of a a framework that is trouble waiting to happen.

Comment: Thanks @M.Deinum that actually resolved my issue. Thanks a lot :)